# Salesforce Label in lightning object

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customlabel

I am trying to create a javascript object inside of a helper method.  What I am trying to accomplish is basically create a map so key=value.  here is the code I have

```
var tabVariables = {
    0 : $A.get("$Label.c.UX_APPLIED_CC"),
    1 : $A.get("$Label.c.UX_SAVED"),
    2 : $A.get("$Label.c.UX_DIRECT"),
    $A.get("$Label.c.UX_APPLIED_CC") : 0
};
```

The first three lines work fine.  the 4th line $A.get("$Label.c.UX_APPLIED_CC") : 0 gives me an error "Unexpected token .".  Any idea if it is possible to do this with the label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you use the object constructor notation, you can't do this. However, you can set it immediately afterwards.

```
tabVariables[$A.get("$Label.c.UX_APPLIED_CC")] = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I needed.